# ifaddrs.h header not found when compiling SDL for android

Tags: android, c++, macos, include, sdl

I'm making an android game with SDL that requires access to ifaddrs.h. when I compile for mac, it works fine. When I compile for Android, it says file not found.

I'm trying to include it like this:

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
```

So I

```
gcc -M network.cpp
```

to find dependancies to the file it's included in, so I can find ifaddrs' absolute location, which is

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/ifaddrs.h
```

so when I

```
#include "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/ifaddrs.h"
```

it finds it, but then errors on including some other dependency of ifaddrs

```
#include <AvailabilityInternal.h>
```

Ok. So, why is the include behavior different when I try to compile for android vs for mac? (using ndkbuild or g++ on mac)? how can I get it to work on android? what piece of knowledge/information am I missing for all this to sense?

(note- currently running OSX yosemite, 10.10)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use MacOSX includes for Android.  Different platforms, different SDKs.

Android does not have its own native `ifaddrs.h` implementation (and thus does not have the `getifaddrs()` function).  However, there is a third-party implementation available:

<strike>https://github.com/kmackay/android-ifaddrs</strike>
https://github.com/morristech/android-ifaddrs
https://www.openhub.net/p/android-ifaddrs/

> An implementation of getifaddrs() for Android, since the NDK does not natively support it.
>
> Works just like you would expect on regular Linux.

Comment: oh my. thank you so much! don't know how I didn't come across that in my searches. makes me feel silly for asking...

Comment: The repository is 404'ed. Fork available e.g. at https://github.com/morristech/android-ifaddrs. However, as https://www.openhub.net/p/android-ifaddrs/commits show this is not the newest version.

Comment: On my device, the code in morristech's repository segfaults when I'm connected via WiFi. The [source](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-beta/source/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/stun/ifaddrs-android.c) and [header](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-beta/source/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/stun/ifaddrs-android.h) files I found in some Mozilla Beta repository worked better. To make it work, I had to remove the `#if defined(ANDROID)` and `#endif`. The `ifaddr` structure misses the members `ifa_addr` and `ifa_dstaddr`. Rename `android_getifaddrs` to `getifaddrs` if you want.

Answer (score 10):

Starting from Android API level 24 (Android 7.0 Nougat) `ifaddrs.h` is supported officially, so, if you target this SDK, you don't need custom implementations anymore.

If you target older version, there is `ifaddrs.h` implementation made by Google, you can find it in Android source code; the most interesting one is Gingerbread implementation, because it is C++ header only one, so you don't need to add it to you project or compile as a separate library, just add it to your includes and use.

The Android Gingerbread `ifaddrs.h` implementation file URL follows:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/gingerbread-release/luni/src/main/native/ifaddrs-android.h

It depends on 2 other include files that you can find in the same repository easily. There are also other `ifaddrs.h` implementations in other Android releases sources, however, they are not header only, so theirs integration requires one additional step.

I tested Gingerbread implementation with 4 devices (Android 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 and 9.0), and I didn't have any issues.

Comment: The missing files are located at:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/gingerbread-release/include/LocalArray.h
and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/gingerbread-release/include/ScopedFd.h